# return Listview items from a function using c#

Tags: c#

I have a function from a button click that will populate the listview. When I call the function there is no data returned to the listview.

I'm not sure what is wrong with my code.
Please enlighten me.

```
public void fn_searchInMacroDatabase(string valueSearch, string valueDbName)
{
    MacroDB macroDB = new MacroDB(); //This the form where the listview is

    string Dbconnection = "DSN=dbname;" + "UID=sics;" + "PWD=sics_1";
    string query = "SELECT * FROM " + valueDbName + " WHERE policy_no = '" + valueSearch + "'";
    
    OdbcConnection cnDB = new OdbcConnection(Dbconnection);
    cnDB.Open();
    OdbcCommand DbCommand = cnDB.CreateCommand();
    DbCommand.CommandText = query;
    OdbcDataReader DbReader = DbCommand.ExecuteReader();

    macroDB.listView1.Columns.Clear();
    macroDB.listView1.Items.Clear();
    macroDB.listView1.GridLines = true;
    macroDB.listView1.View = View.Details;
    macroDB.listView1.Columns.Add("Cession No");
    macroDB.listView1.Columns.Add("URC");
    macroDB.listView1.Columns.Add("Policy No");
    macroDB.listView1.Columns.Add("Cession Type Code");
    macroDB.listView1.AutoResizeColumns((ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize));

    while (DbReader.Read())
    {
        ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem(DbReader[1].ToString());
        lv.SubItems.Add(DbReader[2].ToString());
        lv.SubItems.Add(DbReader[3].ToString());
        lv.SubItems.Add(DbReader[4].ToString());
        macroDB.listView1.Items.Add(lv);
    }
    cnDB.Close();
    DbReader.Close();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your database query return some data?

Comment: yes it does if its not within the function

Comment: BTW why do you create a new `MacroDB` instance inside the function?

Comment: your `MacroDB`-instance only lives within the method where it is declared. So of course it gets destroyed when leaving that method. You should read about scopes in C#: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/ Maybe your form should be a member of the class, instead of a variable in the method?

Comment: I strongly suggest not to fill your listview from the outside, but just push the *data* to your form and let the form modify the listview itself.

Comment: @PeterCsala i have a separate class where i store all my functions. i would have to create that instance to call the listview1 object from other class